# How to capture video from Youtube using HTTP Proxy?

Tags: http, video, youtube, flv, xuggler

I have tested a scenario here a proxy sits between the server and client while browsing youtube videos.

I am sniffing the HTTP traffic, and observe that at least a bunch of SWF files (content-type:Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash) are being received. I am able to store these files on the disk as well.

Now, I am trying to playback these files, but it is not a single file. Not sure why and how youtube server is sending these multiple files.

Questions:
1. How can we interpret these files at the Proxy itself before they reach the Flash player in the browser.
2. How can we process these files (e.g. transcode) at the proxy and then send them to the client. 
3. Are these files independent pieces of informations that Flash player need or these are chunked by the youtube server?

Thanks.

Comment: I am now able to extract the video and audio data payload from the HTTP traffic being intercepted at HTTP proxy. I have used the Xuggler APIs to find out the type of the media (i.e. video or audio). The only problem with my approach is that I am storing the binary payload as a file on disk, and then able to process these files using Xuggler API.